# Test if Table has at least certain Stored Procedure, else fail test c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

This test checks if *only one* SP ends with Insert, Load, or Save, then it's successful.

```
//Query to find SPs for a certain Table name
string check_SP =
    "SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION " +
    "FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES " +
    "WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%CLNT_" + Table_Name + "%' " +
    "AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'";

conn2.Open();
SqlCommand cmd_SP = new SqlCommand(check_SP, conn2);
list_SP = cmd_SP.ExecuteReader(); //Write 'check_SP' query results to 'list_SP'

while (list_SP.Read())
{
    if (list_SP[0].ToString().EndsWith("Insert")
        || list_SP[0].ToString().EndsWith("Load")
        || list_SP[0].ToString().EndsWith("Save"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(list_SP[0]);
        test = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Missing SP");
        test = false;
        break;
    }                    
}
```

What I wanna do is to break the  while loop whenever there is no Stored Procedure that ends with Insert, or Load, or Save. (i.e. Each table should have at least these three SPs or else the test will fail)

Comment: Can't help it: You're doing it wroooooooooong!

Comment: Instead of doing this in your application why not do: `SELECT Suffix FROM (SELECT 'Insert' AS Suffix UNION ALL SELECT 'Load' AS Suffix UNION ALL  SELECT 'Save' AS Suffix ) Suffixes left outer join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES r on ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%CLNT_table_name%' + Suffix AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE' group by Suffix having COUNT(ROUTINE_TYPE) <> 1`

Comment: @Jon: If I were doing it right I won't be making a post here!!

Comment: @Martin: I appreciate your help but I need this in c# code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaving aside whether this is the right way to do this or not, you'll need to change your logic to check for the existence of each type of procedure individually:

```
bool insertExists = false;
bool loadExists = false;
bool saveExists = false;
while (list_SP.Read())
{
    if (list_SP[0].ToString().EndsWith("Insert"))
    {
        insertExists = true;
    }
    if (list_SP[0].ToString().EndsWith("Load"))
    {
        loadExists = true;
    }
    if (list_SP[0].ToString().EndsWith("Save"))
    {
        saveExists = true;
    }
    if (insertExists && loadExists && saveExists)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("All three exist");
        break;
    }
}

if (!insertExists)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Missing insert");
}
if (!loadExists)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Missing load");
}
if (!saveExists)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Missing save");
}
```